# story identification: the Anarchist Party won the elections

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I've read this story a long time ago; this is what I remember:

- The Anarchist Party won the elections, and we listen to its announces as it is now dismantling the State.
- 43 (or was it 41?)-tones Jazz purists bash people who plays different music styles, rhythms or genres.
- Overall, the whole story is based on paradoxes like these.
- Heroin use is, if not mandatory, strongly recommended, and a mob rounds a non-addicted and forcefully injects them with heroin in the story finale, while the radio(?) broadcasts the latest Government announcement that the work of the Anarchist Party is over: no more State, no more Government.

Which story is this?

Comment: About how long is "long time ago"? 40-50 years? Is the story in English? Is it set in the U.S., an unspecified country, a future world state, another planet?

Comment: I think I read it 15-20 years ago. I almost surely read a translated version of the story, so not sure at all about terminology. It was earth, but not sure if it was US or not.

Comment: Could it have been in [*Urania*](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?25960)?

Comment: Yes, very likely

Comment: @user14111 been a while but how about posting that as an answer now? :)

Comment: @user14111 OP did say it could've been in this _Urania_ thing so I don't know, guess I thought something along the lines of "try your story-id magic again" ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ (I'll admit I missed the "**in** _Urania_" and read it as "could it have been _Urania_" at first, sorry!)